# Not able to scroll Raphael Canvas along with Ext Js Grid Panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, raphael

I have created number of grids in a Grid Panel using Ext js. I am connected 2 grids using an arrow created using Raphael. My grid panel is scrollable and when I scroll the grid panel grids are scrolled along with it but he arrows that are created on paper remains where they were created. Please help me out.

Below is the Ext js code for the panel which I have created. I drag and drop grids on this panel.

```
    new Ext.TabPanel({
            id : 'xxx',
            region : 'center',
            deferredRender : false,
            activeTab : 0,
            items : [ {
                id : 'tabId',
                contentEl : 'center1',
                title : 'Editor_DragDrop',
                closable : true,
                autoScroll : true,
                enableDrop : true,
                html : '<div class="hospital-target"></div>',
                listeners : {
                    afterrender : initializeDropZone
                }
            }
       }
```

Below is the code by which I have created a Raphael canvas. I have created it on top of the Panel. This canvas is used to draw arrows between two grids.

```
var width = Ext.getCmp('tabId');
                var tabPos = Ext.getCmp('tabId').getPosition();
                var xpos = this.grid.getWidth() ;
                var ypos = tabPos[1] ;
                this.raphaelCanvas = new Raphael(tabPos[0],ypos,width.getWidth(),width.getHeight());
                canvas=this.raphaelCanvas;
```

Grids are drawn on panel. And arrows are drawn on a raphael canvas that is above panel. They are not actually linked together. When I scroll the panel all the objects that are present on panel are scrolled. But as the canvas is not linked to the panel it remains static.

Below are the images to help you understand it better.

**Before Scrolling:**

[image]

**After Scrolling:**

[image]

Comment: You need to add some HTML to your question.

Comment: I have tried to explain the code that I have written. Let me know if something else need to be added to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Take grid in window.. and catch float / move event of window. and change co ordinates of line according to window's position.